# Difference between entering values in cin using spacebar and enter key?

Tags: c++, cin, difference

What is the difference between inputting a sequence of values for an array of integers in `cin` using a <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and an <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key?

For example -

If I have to input a sequence of numbers in an array and stop receiving the input as soon as `0` is entered by the user in the chain of values. It works correctly if <kbd>ENTER</kbd>  is pressed on the keyboard to separate each number during input whereas on using <kbd>SPACE</kbd> it doesn't stop the input process. Can the below code be modified in some way, so that it works for the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> as well?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   
        int arr[10];
        int i=-1;
        do{
        cin>>arr[++i];
        }while(arr[i]!=0);

        i=-1;

        do{
        cout<<"\n"<<arr[++i];
        }while(arr[i]!=0);
}
```

Comment: Not if what you're typing into doesn't send information until you press enter.

Comment: `int i=-1;` Indexing arrays in c and c++ starts at `0` actually. `cin>>arr[++i];` will be executed on pressing ENTER, space bar doesn't trigger reading.

Comment: I'm using `++i`, so the array index will start from `0` only.

Comment: @SarthakSinghal Ooops, I didn'r spot the `-` actually (misplaced my glasses elsewhere). Though that looks pretty clunky coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"It works correctly if the enter key is pressed to separate each number during input whereas on using the space bar it doesn't stop the input process."*

<kbd>ENTER</kbd> triggers to read the input stream from an input terminal with `cin`, while <kbd>SPACE</kbd> doesn't.

Usually <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from a terminal expands to have the input from the prompt plus a `'\n'` or `'\r'` `'\n'` character sequence sent, and it's considered part of the input.

> *"Can the below code be modified in some way, so that it works for the space bar as well?"*

No, not unless you manage to have a terminal sending input to your program using the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> key.

---

In the end it doesn't really matter for the parsing if you input

```
1 2 3 4 >ENTER
```

or

```
1 2 >ENTER 
3 4 >ENTER
```

`std::istream` will handle receiving `' '`, `'\t'` or `'\n'` characters (see [`std::isspace()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace)) transparently. To send these characters to input is still triggered by the terminal when the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key is pressed.

Comment: Your first statement is misleading: the read starts immediately when `cin` is executed, it's just that there is nothing for `cin` to read until the terminal puts information into `stdin`. The terminal doesn't do that until you press enter.

Answer (score 0):

Space and enter are doing the same thing with respect to `cin`. It's your mechanism of entry (e.g. your terminal program) that is treating space and enter differently: terminals usually don't pass anything along to your program until you hit enter.

To do what you want, you need to use a library that lets you interact with your terminal. (or maybe your terminal has options you can configure to do this)

Comment: Well, ENTER actually triggers the text parsing process, while _space-bar_ doesn't.

Comment: _"Space and enter are doing the same thing with respect to cin."_, No they don't! Are you serious? At least the behavior regarding  triggered  blocking read is completely different.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: Yes, I am: `cin` treats them the same. The cause for the different behavior is elsewhere: e.g. the terminal software that is monitoring keyboard events.